# MySQL count results after MAX timestamp

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I have two tables

mts

- id
- customer_id
- created_at

mos

- id
- customer_id
- created_at

I want to get the last time of an entry in mts and count the results of mos after MAX(mts.created_at). All should be GROUP BY customer_id.

I had the idea of a simple query like this, but this wont work.

```
SELECT id, created_at, COUNT(id) 
FROM mos
WHERE created_at > (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM mts) 
GROUP BY customer_id 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Care to share what error message or unexpected behaviour you encounter?

Comment: Its way too slow, theres no error with the syntax, I get 504 Gateway Timeout

Comment: Sounds like you need to index those columns in the table.

Comment: Okay, this fixed the timeout. But the result is empty, is it because of the query?

Comment: Are you sure that there are records into mos where created_at is bigger than `max(mts.created_at)`?

Answer (score 0):

This SQL-Statement will just give you 1 single line in the result set (not matter what). Everything that is not part of an aggregate-function should by contained in `GROUP BY`.

Your SQL-Statement should look like this:

```
SELECT id, created_at, COUNT(id) 
FROM mos
WHERE created_at > (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM mts) 
GROUP BY customer_id, id, created_at
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: `SELECT customer_id, MAX(created_at) created_at, COUNT(customer_id) FROM mts WHERE created_at > (SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM mos WHERE customer_id = 2) AND customer_id = 2 GROUP BY customer_id` this works if i add another AND and WHERE, but I want this as a listing.